# Flex: how to reference an object itself?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to print the content of the label property in the Alert window.

```
<mx:LinkButton label="{bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.name}" click="Alert.show(this.label.toString())" />
```

But the Alert window is completely empty. What am I doing wrong ?

I guess the keyword "this" is referencing the application instead of the LinkButton, right ?
How can I reference the LinkButton itself, without having to add an ID to all my linkButtons ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work quite like Javascript. You'll have to do this:

```
<mx:LinkButton label="{bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.name}" click="Alert.show(event.currentTarget.label.toString())" />
```

That should alert the value of the label.